# Why does Microsoft Excel change the characters that I copy into it?

Tags: wine, microsoft-office

I live in Spain and I am using the English version of Microsoft Excel installed with wine on Ubuntu.
The problem is that I use my laptop at work and when I copy text into excel (text that is Spanish) the characters that are Spanish (such as é,ñ, á...etc) are changed into weird characters. How can I sort this out?

For example:
Martínez José....appears as "MartÃ­nez JosÃ©" in my spreadsheet and I really cant have it this way or my boss will kill me. :)

Comment: Encoding issue possibly?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I dont even know what that means. :)

Comment: such weird issues occur when you emulate through wine, there is a solution, I'm sure, but it might be difficult to track, one solution would be to use a native linux app like libre office, it can save to Excel formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding problem anyway it may be hard to solve this issue for you. But you can use **Libreoffice Calc** it looks like **Microsoft office excel** and also you can save in **Microsoft office** formats(xls-xlsx)

Comment: well, the thing is that I'd like to use microsoft excel. That's the software I am used to.